# Python detect broken encoding

Tags: python, encoding

After crawling many websites, in some of them i receive broken-encoding data. I can't do anything with them, i just need to detect them. For example text like:

> ·ç¼wÃdª«¦Ê³f

or

> ãà³n³¾å¢

How can I recognize text like that ? I any language, so searching for non-english text is not an option. The only option I can think of is **guess-language** module.

Comment: [`chardet`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) may be of interest to you too. Also, try to respect the HTTP content-type header and `<meta>` header tag for the content type, while keeping in mind they're also quite often wrong :-)

Comment: cchardet is even better, it's much faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) which has a [`guess_encoding`](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.util.guess_encoding) function that takes a byte string and tries all of the available encodings, would this serve your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy

If I understand correctly, it will attempt to 'repair' incorrectly encoded/decoded text.